# JQuery Bootstrap selectpicker on('change') set selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable and default-select a `<select>` based on the value on another select. When I first select one option in `<select>` choixVarX (e.g. "Pop"), `<select>` parametresX does exactly what I want it to do: disable the first two `<optgroup>` and default-select "pasCentre" and "noDispersion". However, when I change  choixVarX to another one not triggering the behavior I want (e.g. "PropRetraite") and then change it again to one triggering the behavior I want (e.g. "FoyersImposes" or "FoyersFiscaux"), the second `<select>` parametresX behaves weirdly: the two first `<optgroup>` are disabled, but "pasCentre" and "noDispersion" are NOT default-selected... Any clue?

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="choixVarX" id="choixVarX" size="1" onChange="populateMap('#DDDDC2','#000000',listeComparaison);">
        <option value="Pop">Population</option>
        <option value="FoyersImposes">Nombre de foyers imposés</option>
        <option value="FoyersFiscaux">Nombre de foyers fiscaux</option>
        <option value="PropRetraite">Part des retraites dans les revenus</option>
        <option value="PropFoyersImposes">Proportion de foyers imposés</option>
        <option value="RevMoyen">Revenu moyen</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple name="parametresX[]" id="parametresX" size="1" data-width="150px" onChange="populateMap('#DDDDC2','#000000',listeComparaison);" data-max-options="3">
      <optgroup label="Centrage des données" data-max-options="1" id="centrageX">
        <option value="median">Médiane des communes</option>
        <option value="moyenne">Moyenne des communes</option>
        <option value="pasCentre">Ne pas centrer</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Dispersion" id="dispersionX" data-max-options="1">
        <option value="minmax">Min-Max</option>
        <option value="ecarttype">Ecart-type</option>
        <option value="noDispersion">Aucun</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Echelle" id="echelleX" data-max-options="1">
        <option value="echelleComplete">Echelle étendue</option>
        <option value="echelleAdaptee">Echelle réduite</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

$('#choixVarX').on('change',function(){
  if($('#choixVarX').val()=="FoyersImposes" || $('#choixVarX').val()=="FoyersFiscaux" || $('#choixVarX').val()=="Pop"){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    $('#centrageX option[value="median"]').attr('selected',false);
    $('#centrageX option[value="moyenne"]').attr('selected',false);    
    $('#centrageX option[value="pasCentre"]').attr('selected',true);
    $('#dispersionX option[value="minmax"]').attr('selected',false);
    $('#dispersionX option[value="ecarttype"]').attr('selected',false);
    $('#dispersionX option[value="noDispersion"]').attr('selected',true);
    $('#centrageX').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#dispersionX').attr('disabled',true);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  }else{
    $('#centrageX').attr('disabled',false);
    $('#dispersionX').attr('disabled',false);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

Comment: you better provide a jsfiddle, so we can see the problem! and tinker it for you

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/60c2ddgt/ . I really don't get where my problem is coming from!

Comment: The proper fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/lecocodebelleville/txy4teks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be a solution for you, I changed your attr to prop insed and made a switch isted of the long if-statment. unfortunately the data-max-options="1" don't work must be at least data-max-options="2". So hope it helps, you can se the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/txy4teks/1/

```
$('#choixVarX').on('change', function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'Pop':
        case 'FoyersImposes':
        case 'FoyersFiscaux':
            $('#centrageX option[value="median"]').prop('selected', false);
            $('#centrageX option[value="moyenne"]').prop('selected', false);
            $('#centrageX option[value="pasCentre"]').prop('selected', true);
            $('#dispersionX option[value="minmax"]').prop('selected', false);
            $('#dispersionX option[value="ecarttype"]').prop('selected', false);
            $('#dispersionX option[value="noDispersion"]').prop('selected', true);
            $('#centrageX').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#dispersionX').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            break;    
        case 'PropRetraite':
        case 'PropFoyersImposes':
        case 'RevMoyen':
            $('#centrageX').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#dispersionX').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and despite what you said, it's also working with data-max-options="1"! Cheers!